# Conditional Probability A Box Of Fuses?

Tags: probability, statistics

> A box of fuses contain $20$ fuses, of which five are defective. If three of the fuses are selected at random and removed from the box in succession without replacement what is the probability that all three fuses are defective?

For this question I know that one must use the formula 
$$P \left(A \cap B \cap C \right ) = P(A) * P(B|A) * P(C| A \cap B)$$

I am able to to identify that $P(A) = \frac{5}{20}$. I assume since their are five out of 20 defective fuses. My question for this probelm is how does one identify $P(B|A) \text{ and }  P(C| A \cap B)$?

I know that $P(B|A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{p(A)}$ and $ P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{p(A)} $

Unfortunately identifying how one solves this problem eludes my understanding any advice on how to solve this would be beneficial to I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am able to identify that $P(A)=5/20$. I assume since their are five out of 20 defective fuses. My question for this probelm is how does one identify $P(B|A)$ and $P(C|A∩B)$?

Second verse, same as the first.

$\mathsf P(B\mid A) = 4/19$ because when given that you have selected one defective fuse there are 4 defectives left among the 19 remaining.

$\mathsf P(C\mid A\cap B) = 3/18$ for some obscure reason.

So $\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C) =\dfrac{~~5\cdot ~~4\cdot ~~3}{20\cdot 19\cdot 18}$

As others have pointed out this equals ${\binom 5 3}\big/{\binom {20} 3}$, from comparing counts: ways to select 3 from 5 defectives (and no non-defectives) versus ways to select any 3 from 20.

Comment: "$\mathsf P(C\mid A\cap B) = 3/18$ for some obscure reason." What is this obsure reason if I may ask?

Comment: A joke.  Obviously its the same reason.

Comment: I presumed as much I just wanted your confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done combinations, you see that there are ${{5}\choose{3}} = 10$ ways to choose any 3 of the 5 defective fuses. There are ${{20}\choose{3}} = 1140$ ways of choosing 3 fuses at random from the 20 fuses. Therefore, the chance for all fuses to be defective is $\frac{10}{1140} = \frac{1}{114}$.

Comment: I want to learn the way the book teaches it. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

you can straightforwardly apply the **hypergeometrical distribution** here:

*Given a box with $x$ black and $y$ white balls, the probability $P$ of choosing (without replacement) $n$ balls, such that $k$ are black and the rest $n-k$ are white is given by 
$$
P=\frac{\binom{x}{k}\binom{y}{n-k}}{\binom{x+y}{n}}
$$*
In your problem, $x=5$, $y=15$, $n=3$, $k=3$, so 
$$
P=\frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{15}{0}}{\binom{20}{3}}=\frac{1}{114}
$$

Comment: I did not know their were so many different ways to solve this.